# Wacky Geometry Fix?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, geometry

I've been struggling with this model that I'm making for VRChat recently, and I've been at a roadblock for some time now.

In my model, there's some weird geometry that I've really got no idea how to fix. I've changed "Alt + N" 'd multiple times (sometimes working, sometimes not), used the smooth vertices tool, moved the points around and everything. You'd think that you could just throw on autosmooth, or some modifier, but this is all for the visemes of the character (the mouth movements) which complicates things more than I'd like.

I'm a beginner to Blender (and the CATS plugin, if that matters), I'll attach some photos to see if they can do a better job at explaining what in the world is happening here.

Thanks ^^!

[image: Side of the maw at an angle in object mode]

[[image: Side of the maw at an angle in edit vertices mode]]

[image: Straight side of the maw in object mode]

(don't roast me for the shape ;w;)

Comment: If you go into sculpt mode and hit it with the smooth brush does it give you what you want?

Comment: Welcome to the site! As you mentioned you're a beginner to Blender, I personally (sorry) think you're in a little over your head. You can fix the topology you're talking about, but you really need a basic understanding of modeling to do so. Learn how to slide vertices, join them, re-route edge loops, form quads, use the knife tool effectively, etc. I would suggest you take a few modeling tutorials before tackling this issue.

Comment: i'm 100% over my head! but nonetheless, i feel like i've come too far to stop, and am almost done with this entire thing. do you know any places that could help me with learning how to do those things, specific videos you'd suggest and all ^^?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid stretched faces and triangles, it will create artefacts, try to create a topology that follows the shape of your object, something like that:

[image]